# Predator-Prey System

Tags: graphing-functions, curves

> On an isolated island live a population of rabbits and a population of wolves. Let **x(t)** and
>   **y(t)** be the numbers of rabbits and wolves on the island at time t, respectively. Our goal is to
>   model **x(t)** and **y(t)**. As is typical in modelling problems, we model quantities by describing
>   their evolution over time, i.e., their rates of change. Assume that this evolution is governed
>   by the following rules:

```
(1) The rabbits have an infinite food supply. The rabbit population grows at a rate 
proportional to its size.
(2) The rabbits are eaten by the wolves at a rate proportional to the sizes of both rabbit
and wolf populations. Getting eaten by a wolf is the only way a rabbit dies.
(3) The population of rabbits is the only food source for the wolves. The wolf population
grows at a rate proportional to the sizes of both rabbit and wolf populations.
(4) The wolves are mortal; their population declines at a rate proportional to its size.
```

Thus, the populations are modeled by the following system of first-order differential equations: **(this is the *)**
$$x'(t) = ax(t) - bx(t)y(t)$$
$$y'(t) = cx(t)y(t) - dy(t)$$

Exercise 3.

- If x(t) $\ge$ 0 and $x'(t) = 0$, then $y(t) =$ _____. If y(t) $\ge$ 0 and $y'(t) = 0$, then
  $x(t) $ = ______. Your answers should be lines in the $xy$-plane. Plot them.
- On the same plot, indicate the following regions:

$$R_{++} = {(x(t); y(t)) \in [0;1) * [0;1) : x_0(t) > 0 \,\text{and } y_0(t) > 0} $$
$$R_{+-} = {(x(t); y(t)) \in [0;1) * [0;1) : x_0(t) > 0 \,\text{and } y_0(t) < 0};$$
$$R_{-+} = {(x(t); y(t)) \in [0;1) * [0;1) : x_0(t) < 0 \,\text{and } y_0(t) > 0};$$
$$R_{--} = {(x(t); y(t)) \in [0;1) * [0;1) : x_0(t) < 0 \,\text{and } y_0(t) < 0}:$$

- On the same plot, roughly sketch some parametric "population trajectory" curves $(x(t), y(t))$ satisfying (* - equations above). Indicate direction along the curves with arrowheads.

So far I've found out that 
$$y(t) = a/b$$
$$x(t) = d/c$$
But I don't know how to plot the "population trajectory" curves.

Comment: I would follow this page: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DirectionFields.aspx

Comment: What software are you using to plot ?.